# My code for NSUserDefaults is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am very new to swift. And need your help!
I want that, when the user logs in for the second time , the app should directly take it to the next view controller named CoreView. It should not ask for details, but I don't know why its not working. And it's asking for details everytime the app is launched. Please check the below code. I am not getting any sort of error too. Unless and until the app is killed or logged out, the user should be able to log in directly .

```
func pref_write()
{
    // To write the  data to NSUserDefaults

    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() // make a reference
    print("OTP:\(OTP)")

    // Adding values. Creating objects in prefs
    prefs.setObject(OTP, forKey: "OTP")
    print("check_OTP:\(check_OTP)")

    prefs.setObject(U_ID, forKey: "U_ID")
    print("Check_U_ID:\(check_U_ID)")
    prefs.synchronize()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ContinueToCoreView", sender: self)

}
```

And in the viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Read the data
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ContinueToCoreView", sender: self)
    pref_write()
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    check_OTP = prefs.objectForKey("OTP")!
    check_U_ID = prefs.objectForKey("U_ID")!
    prefs.objectForKey("U_ID")
    print("prefs:\(prefs)")
    prefs.synchronize()

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want only to keep an state while application is running and you do not want to keep the state when the app killed; so you do not need to store the state in the 'UserDefaults'.
Anyway, if you store some state in 'UserDefaults' you should check the stored value and based on its value make your decision. I can not see any checks in your code on values that you store in 'UserDefaults'.

Comment: Firstly, I want to store the data, and not the state. When I am creating objects in prefs. It should get stored there. And If I am wrong in any way.. please guide me through this. I want to store the details in UserDefaults till the moment the app is killed.

Comment: In write method you are writing by correct way but in viewDidLoad you are only reading the values and never check them and also before reading them you are call write method that probably do not make sense. Also you are always firing the "ContinueToCoreView" segue that do not make sense too. Is it the viewDidLoad of your first view controller?

Comment: Yes, it is the first view controller. Please help..

Comment: What should I do according to you, to save the data and then fire the segue the second time user logs in..?

Comment: When user login, then you should store the value in 'UserDefaults' and when again user opened your app and firstViewController opend on the ViewDidLoad you should check the values that saved and if they was expected values (according to your logic) then call the segue.
Just please notice that if you only want to keep the state while your app are running, so you do not need to save the state in 'UserDefaults' only use an app variable. Something like a static variable or an object that is live while your app is live.

Comment: Which viewController is loading when you are calling segue identifier "ContinueToCoreView"?

Comment: The first login page View controller is the initial view controller. And if the the user is logging in for the second time, the login page should be seen, ir should directly take to the next view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class as

```
class User_Details : NSObject
{
    var user_id : String?
    var user_otp : String?
    var otp_verified : Bool?

    init(u_id:String, otp:String?, verified:Bool)
    {
        super.init()
        self.user_id = u_id
        self.otp_verified = verified
        self.user_otp = otp
    }
}
```

In **AppDelegate**,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    navController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    if self.checkIfUserLoggedIn()
    {
        let user_details = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("user_details") as! User_Details
        self.moveToNextScreen(user_details)
    }
    return true
}

//AppDelegate Class or in the class which is globally accessible
func pref_write_user(user_details : User_Details)
{
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    prefs.setObject(user_details, forKey: "user_details")
    prefs.setBool(true, forKey: "is_user_login")

    //After saving the OTP for current user, check for otp verified, move to OTP Screen
    self.moveToNextScreen(user_details)
}

func moveToNextScreen(user_details : User_Details)
{
    if user_details.otp_verified == false
    {
        // Move to OTP screen
        let viewController = self.navController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("otpScreen")
        self.navController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: false)
    }
    else // Move to Home Screen
    {
        let viewController = self.navController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeScreen")
        self.navController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: false)
    }
}

func logoutUser()
{
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    prefs.setObject(nil, forKey: "user_details")
    prefs.setBool(false, forKey: "is_user_login")
}

func checkIfUserLoggedIn() -> Bool
{
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if prefs.boolForKey("is_user_login")
    {
        if let _ = prefs.objectForKey("user_details")
        {
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            //User details not found for some reason, so setting the inital values and return false
            self.logoutUser()
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

**Login Class** :
Call the API for login by providing the basic credential, get the user_id and user_otp, save them to NSUserDefaults

```
func requestLoginToServer()
{
    //Perform basic server action
    ....
    //In Success Block write this
    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    // pass the values as return by the server
    let user_details = User_Details(u_id: "123", otp: "1234", verified: false) 
    appDel.pref_write_user(user_details)
    appDel.moveToNextScreen(user_details)
}
```

Comment: I am very new to this. I am not getting what you are saying.. I trie your code. but it gives me error. can you please share your contact ID or number so that I can cannot you and clear away my doubt. This project is very important to me and I hardly have any time to deliver this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way. I just rearranged your code.
  First it will check the login credentials with in the didload method of initial view controller.      If it not there it will call the method  **pref_write()** .     Please make sure that the values used in  pref_write() method are not nil

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    // You can give conditions for your need like  if(prefs.valueForKey("U_ID") != nil))
    // It will check the user defaults whether you already login
    if(prefs.valueForKey("OTP") != nil) {   

          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ContinueToCoreView", sender: self)
    }

    else{

         pref_write()
    } 
}


 // Make sure the Values are not nil

 func pref_write()
 {
      // To write the  data to NSUserDefaults

      let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() // make a reference
      print("OTP:\(OTP)")

     // Adding values. Creating objects in prefs
      prefs.setObject(OTP, forKey: "OTP")
      print("check_OTP:\(check_OTP)")

      prefs.setObject(U_ID, forKey: "U_ID")
      print("Check_U_ID:\(check_U_ID)")
      prefs.synchronize()
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ContinueToCoreView", sender: self)

}
```

Hope its working...